# step into skips method in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I want to debug step by step my code but the debugger skips my function method whenever I click the step into option in Visual Studio 2015.

My code

```
   _watch.Created += this.FileCreated;

   public void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e1)
   {
      // some code
   }
```

I attached a break point to `_watch.Created += this.FileCreated;` and then I clicked the step into option but the debugger skips the `FileCreated` method. Can anyone tell me how to step into this method?

Comment: Put breakpoint inside your event handler, then it will hit when your event will be called.

Comment: By registering to some event, you will not actually call it. It will be called when (in your example) file will be created.

Comment: thanks @SeM for reply :) I am new to .net . I will try your way . Can you tell me what is _watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a break point on

```
_watch.Created += this.FileCreated;
```

won't trigger the method. It's assigning the method to run when `Created` is invoked.

You want to put a break point on

```
public void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e1)
```

and then, when the `Created` event is invoked, your break point will hit and you can step into the method.

**Links from comments:**

[Raising and Handling Events MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/index)

[Examples of raising and consuming events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)

Comment: thanks for reply :) . I am new to .net. I attached breakpoint to FileCreated method but debugger skips that also . one more qs can you tell me what is _watch??

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, I am not sure what _watch is. You have the code! Are you following a tutorial? You are basically using events and delegates. Have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/index) for more info.

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, at a glance it looks like `_watch` is an object of type `FileSystemWatcher`. I believe that when you create a new file in the directory the `FileSystemWatcher` is watching, then the `FileCreated` method will run and you can debug it.

Comment: I went through some tutorial like w3school and tutorial points and some other youtube videos but none of that is sufficient or just say good tutorial . Can you suggest any good site to learn that will be very helpful.

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, try [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events). Run the examples, put break points in and read up on Events and Delegates.

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, I've added the links to my answer, if you find them helpful then accept and upvote the answer to help others.